# html button causes postback before ajax call

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have what I think is a fairly standard HTML form for sending a "booking" email, sitting inside a popup div. On submit I'd like it to send the form data through AJAX to an ashx handler (in order to store the booking and send an email), however the button causes a postback before the ajax is processed and I can't seem to find a way around it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
            <div class="popup">
              <h2>Book a Table:</h2>
              <a class="close" href="#">
                <i class="pe-7s-close"></i>
              </a>
              <div class="content">
                <form id="booking_form" method="post" action="Bookings.ashx">
                  <div class="form-section">
                    <div>
                      <label>Booking Name:</label>
                      <div>
                        <input type="text" id="input_name" name="name" data-id="id-name" value="" required="true"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label>E-mail:</label>
                      <div>
                        <input type="email" id="input_email" name="email" data-id="id-email" size="30" value="" required="true"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label>Phone:</label>
                      <div>
                        <input type="text" data-type="input-textbox" id="input_phone" name="phone" data-id="id-phone" size="20" value="" maxlength="100" required="true"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label>Number of Guests:</label>
                      <div>
                        <input type="text" data-type="input-textbox" id="input_guests" name="guests" data-id="id-guests" size="3" value="" maxlength="100" required="true"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label>Date:</label>
                      <div>
                        <input type="text" id="datepicker" required="true" name="date" data-id="id-date"/>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label>Time:</label>
                      <div>
                        <select class="form-dropdown" style="width:150px" id="time" data-id="id-time[]" required="true">
                          <option value="">  </option>
                          <option value="11:30 am"> 11:30 am </option>
                          <option value="12:00 pm"> 12:00 pm </option>
                          <option value="12:30 pm"> 12:30 pm </option>
                          <option value="1:00 pm"> 1:00 pm </option>
                          <option value="1:30 pm"> 1:30 pm </option>
                          <option value="closed"> </option>
                          <option value="5:00 pm"> 5:00 pm </option>
                          <option value="5:30 pm"> 5:30 pm </option>
                          <option value="6:00 pm"> 6:00 pm </option>
                          <option value="6:30 pm"> 6:30 pm </option>
                          <option value="7:00 pm"> 7:00 pm </option>
                          <option value="7:30 pm"> 7:30 pm </option>
                          <option value="8:00 pm"> 8:00 pm </option>
                          <option value="8:30 pm"> 8:30 pm </option>
                        </select>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                      <label> Any Special Request? </label>
                      <div>
                        <textarea id="input_notes" cols="40" name="notes" data-id="id-notes" rows="5"></textarea>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-line">
                      <div>
                        <div>
                          <button type="submit">
                            Book Now
                          </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

**JS/AJAX**

```
$(function () {
    // Get the form.
    var form = $('#booking_form');

    // Set up an event listener for the contact form.
    $(form).submit(function (event) {
        // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
        event.preventDefault();

        // Serialize the form data.
        var formData = $(form).serialize();
        var querystring = "";
        querystring += "&name=" + $('input[name=name]').attr('data-id');
        querystring += "&email=" + $('input[name=email]').attr('data-id');
        querystring += "&phone=" + $('input[name=phone]').attr('data-id');
        querystring += "&guests=" + $('input[name=guests]').attr('data-id');
        querystring += "&date=" + $('input[name=date]').attr('data-id');
        querystring += "&time=" + $('input[name=time]').attr('data-id');
        querystring += "&notes=" + $('input[name=notes]').attr('data-id');
        // Submit the form using AJAX.
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: $(form).attr('Bookings.ashx?method=ProcessRequest&'+querystring),
            data: formData
        }).done(function (response) {

            // Clear the form.
            $('#input_name').val('');
            $('#input_email').val('');
            $('#input_phone').val('');
            $('#input_guests').val('');
            $('#datepicker').val('');
            $('#time').val('');
            $('#input_notes').val('');
        }).fail(function (data) {

            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

**ASHX**

```
public class Bookings : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        HttpRequest Request = context.Request;
        HttpResponse Response = context.Response;
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        string name = Request["name"].ToString();
        string email = Request["email"].ToString();
        string phone = Request["phone"].ToString();
        Int32 guests = Int32.Parse(Request["guests"].ToString());
        DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(Request["date"].ToString());
        string time = Request["time"].ToString();
        string notes = Request["notes"].ToString();

        con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbConn"]);
        cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.AddBooking", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Name", name);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Email", email);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Phone", phone);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Guests", guests);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Date", date);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Time", time);
        if (notes.Length == 0)
        {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Notes",null);
        }
        else { 
        cmd.Parameters.Add("Notes", notes);
        }
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Int32 bookNo = 0;
        cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetLastBookingNo", con);
        bookNo = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("bookings@site.local", "me@gmail.com");
        mm.Subject = "Booking Ref:" + bookNo;
        mm.Body = "Name: " + name + "<br /><br />Email: " + email + "<br /><br />Guests: " + guests.ToString() + "<br /><br />Date: " + date.ToString() + "<br /><br />Time: " + time + "<br /><br />Notes: " + notes;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Send(mm);

    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like the data you are sending in AJAX's data property is same as your query string. One of them seems unnecessary.

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` should prevent the normal post. If it's not working, there may be an error somewhere in your Javascript, so the `$(form).submit()` is not running. Check your Javascript console for errors.

Comment: Why are you putting `.attr("data-id")` in the query string, instead of `.val()`?

Answer (score 1):

Switch the button type to "button". `type="submit"` will cause the default post behavior.

Alternative: Add a click handler to the button and add `return false` at the end of the click handler. This will prevent the normal post behavior.

Example:

```
function submit() {
    // Stop the browser from submitting the form.
    event.preventDefault();

    // Serialize the form data.
    var formData = $(form).serialize();
    var querystring = "";
    querystring += "&name=" + $('input[name=name]').attr('data-id');
    querystring += "&email=" + $('input[name=email]').attr('data-id');
    querystring += "&phone=" + $('input[name=phone]').attr('data-id');
    querystring += "&guests=" + $('input[name=guests]').attr('data-id');
    querystring += "&date=" + $('input[name=date]').attr('data-id');
    querystring += "&time=" + $('input[name=time]').attr('data-id');
    querystring += "&notes=" + $('input[name=notes]').attr('data-id');
    // Submit the form using AJAX.
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $(form).attr('Bookings.ashx?method=ProcessRequest&'+querystring),
        data: formData
    }).done(function (response) {

        // Clear the form.
        $('#input_name').val('');
        $('#input_email').val('');
        $('#input_phone').val('');
        $('#input_guests').val('');
        $('#datepicker').val('');
        $('#time').val('');
        $('#input_notes').val('');
    }).fail(function (data) {

        return false;
    });

    return false;
}
```

The Button:

`<button type="submit" onclick="submit();">Book now</button>`

Comment: If the button type is not submit it will not create a submit event. Because the browser will not understand that there is a button trying to submit a form. So the way around I can think is still make the button type = "button" but instead of trying to catch the submit event of the form, try to catch button's click event. From that point you can do whatever you want

Comment: `event.preventDefault()` prevents the default submit. It's not necessary to change the button type.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately it still just refreshes the page before it gets to the Ajax call.